# Griddata creating bad shapes scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gaussian, interpolation

I am using this [code](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bxv8ab9PeMQVbGRLdGktQXpQb0k/edit) to visualise my data using griddata. The code looks like this:

```
import math 
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


**THE LIST C=DATA IS IN THE LINK ABOVE**

cx=np.asarray([row[0] for row in C])
cy=np.asarray([row[1] for row in C])
cz=np.asarray([row[2] for row in C])

xi = np.linspace(22.4,22.5,10)
yi = np.linspace(37,37.1,10)
# grid the data.
zi = griddata((cx, cy), cz, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='nearest')

plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,300,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
# draw colorbar
plt.colorbar() 

plt.xlim(xmin=22.4,xmax=22.5)
plt.ylim(ymin=37,ymax=37.1)
plt.title('no diamonds please')
plt.show()
```

As you can see there are some diamond shaped shapes which in fact should have been like the contours of a gaussian like for example shown [here](http://www.google.com/imgres?start=312&hl=el&biw=1600&bih=730&tbs=imgo:1&tbm=isch&tbnid=RndWbW1jVB4oZM%3a&imgrefurl=http://ammar-hakim.org/sj/je/je1/je1-periodic-poisson.html&docid=ukuFb9_h0EExhM&imgurl=http://ammar-hakim.org/sj/_images/s2-periodic-poisson_2d_src_sol.png&w=800&h=600&ei=FyERUNCPD8f34QTg34DoBA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=1087&vpy=408&dur=472&hovh=194&hovw=259&tx=104&ty=104&sig=106447174075007480182&page=12&tbnh=161&tbnw=215&ndsp=28&ved=1t:429,r:25,s:312,i:176)

Am i doing something wrong? Should i use some other tool instead of griddata? I had problems using sagemath for this and now switched to ""pure" python. Noob level keep in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Silly as it is, the answer is just to increase the value of "stepsize" in linspace like i.e:

```
xi = np.linspace(22.4,22.5,100)
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got sort of similar shaped "tiles" of different colors rather than 3 Gaussian humps.